# A question on the expansion of $(1-x)^n$

Tags: calculus, combinatorics

Suppose we are given $f(x)=(1-x)^n$, where $x \in (0,1)$, and $n$ is an positive integer. We can rewrite $f(x)$ as

\begin{equation}
f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i} (-x)^i = 1 - nx + \sum_{i=2}^n\binom{n}{i}(-x)^i.
\end{equation}

In particular, we want to decide the sign of the term $\sum_{i=2}^n\binom{n}{i}(-x)^j$, which are higher-order terms of $x$. I looked at some small $n$'s, and it seems that these terms are always positive, e.g.,

\begin{align}
n&=3:\sum_{i=2}^3\binom{3}{i}(-x)^i=3x^2-x^3=x^2(3-x)>0;\\
n&=4:\sum_{i=2}^4\binom{4}{i}(-x)^i=6x^2-4x^3+x^4=4x^2(1-x)+2x^2+x^4>0;\\
n&=5:\sum_{i=2}^5\binom{5}{i}(-x)^i=10x^2-10x^3+5x^4-x^5=10x^2(1-x)+x^4(5-x)>0.
\end{align}
Through numerical results, this seems to be true for even larger $n$. But how can we prove this result for general $n$. Is there anyone having an idea?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli's_inequality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It follows from the closely related [Bernoulli's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality) which says that for $n\ge2$ and $x\ge-1$
$$(1+x)^n\ge1+nx$$
with equality only when $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Denote $p_n(x):=(1-x)^n-(1-nx)$. Then 
$$p_{n+1}(x)-p_n(x)=x(1-(1-x)^n)\geqslant 0,$$
hence $p_n(x)\geqslant p_2(x)\geqslant x^2$,
which gives the result.